# Using the "AND" operator in with linq

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, expression

I'm trying to do an expression some like this:

```
from a in objcxt.tableA
join b in objcxt.tableB
on a.fld1 equals b.fld1 and a.fld2 equals b.fld2
into b_join from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

edit: b.fld2 can be null.

I tryed "and", "&&", but no success.

Some help?

Comment: is not working for me bro... what is gonna happening?

Comment: Do you get a compile error, or does it bring back results you don't want?  "&&" OR "and" should work equally well.  More details please.

Comment: maybe this is what you need: [How to: Join by Using Composite Keys (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
from a in objcxt.tableA
join b in objcxt.tableB
on
    new { a.fld1, a.fld2 }
equals
    new { b.fld1, b.fld2 }
into b_join from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: I got the error: "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'" using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend, the problem is that I comparing an int? and int type. Regards

Answer (score 3):

You need to write it to work with the ***equals*** operator, which can only be used once after an ***on*** statement.  So, something like this is needed.

```
from a in objcxt.tableA
join b in objcxt.tableB
on new { a.fld1, a.fld2 } equals new { b.fld1, b.fld2 }
into b_join from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for the answer, but I'm getting this error when I try to use it:
"The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'"

Comment: Thanks a lot friend, the problem is that I comparing an int? and int type.
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an anonymous type in your join to specify multiple fields in the join.

```
on new {a.fld1, a.fld2} equals new {b.fld1, b.fld2}
```